# Getting error: Model reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am getting the following error on the below line:

"Model reference not set to instance of an object"

```
<select asp-for="FilmGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres">
```

I am including the file below for reference.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

```
@model MvcFilm.Models.FilmGenreViewModel
<!-- allows you to access the list of movies that the controller passed to the view by using a Model object that's strongly typed.-->
<!-- Because the Model object is strongly typed (as an IEnumerable object), each item in the loop is typed as Film. -->
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    }

    <h1>Index</h1>

    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>

    <form asp-controller="Films" asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <p>

            <select asp-for="FilmGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres">
                <option value="">All</option>
            </select>


            Title:
            <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </p>
    </form>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Films[0].Title)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Films[0].ReleaseDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Films[0].Genre)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Films[0].Price)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model.Films)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My model file: // FilmGenreViewModel.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace MvcFilm.Models
    {
        public class FilmGenreViewModel
            // Films Genre view: Contains:
                // - A list of films
                // - A select list covering a list of genres.
                // - A searchstring, which contains text that the users enter into the the search text box.
        {
            public List<Film> Films { get; set; }
            public SelectList Genres { get; set; }
            public string FilmGenre { get; set; }
            public string SearchString { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

My controller file: FilmsController.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using MvcFilm.Data;
    using MvcFilm.Models;
    
    namespace MvcFilm.Controllers
    {
        public class FilmsController : Controller
        {
            private readonly MvcFilmContext _context;
    
            public object FilmGenreVM { get; private set; }
    
            public FilmsController(MvcFilmContext context)
            {
                _context = context; // constructor uses dependency injection to inject the database context into the controller.
            }
    
            // GET: Films
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string filmGenre, string searchString)
            {
                // Use LINQ to get a list of genres.
                IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Film select m.Genre;
                var films = from m in _context.Film
                             select m;
    
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    films = films.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
                }
    
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filmGenre))
                {
                    films = films.Where(x => x.Genre == filmGenre);
                }
    
                var filmGenreVM = new FilmGenreViewModel
                {
                    Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                    Films = await films.ToListAsync()
                };
    
                return View(FilmGenreVM);
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the code of your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised the issue - it's a capitalization problem:

```
            var filmGenreVM = new FilmGenreViewModel
            {
                Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                Films = await films.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(FilmGenreVM);
        }
```

Should be:

```
        var filmGenreVM = new FilmGenreViewModel
        {
            Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
            Films = await films.ToListAsync()
        };
    
        return View(filmGenreVM);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Object that passed to View from Controller method is null.
In the end of controller method should exists code like that:

```
        var filmGenreViewModel = new FilmGenreViewModel();
        //some code for initialize filmGenreViewModel may be here
        return View(filmGenreViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to use Select Tag helpers to render a SELECT element. You should set the view model's Genres type as `List<SelectListItem>`.

Like below:

```
public class CreateEmployeeViewModelData
{
    //Other properties
    public List<SelectListItem> Genres { set; get; }
}
```

Then you should build it in the controller method as below:

```
        return View(new CreateEmployeeViewModelData { 
           Genres=  new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Text = "Shyju", Value = "1"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "Sean", Value = "2"}
}                
            );
    }
```

Usage:

All

Result:

[image]

Besides, if the `Genres` is a list of class like below:

```
public class CreateEmployeeViewModelData
{
    //Other properties
    public List<Student> Genres { set; get; }
}
```

You could set it in controller like this:

```
        return View(new CreateEmployeeViewModelData { 
           Genres=  new List<Student>
{
    new Student{Name = "Shyju", Id = "1"},
    new Student{Name = "Sean", Id = "2"}
}                
            );
    }
```

Then you could new SelectListItem  in the select tag helper as below:

```
        <select asp-for="FilmGenre" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Genres,"Id","Name"))">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Hi @Brando Zhang,

Comment: This is all very well and good, but when I set it in my controller I have to do a type conversion:

```Genres = new List<SelectListItem>((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),```

and when I run the code I get an InvalidCastException:
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1."

It might work better with the code I had previously - I have edited the above question to include both controller & model files

Comment: Any further comments @Brando Zhang (based on my model and controller - now included in my code excerpts above?)

Comment: Could you please share the result of the `genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()`.Does its type is string?

Comment: Hi @Brando Zhang, yes I believe it is.

Comment: See attached screenshot above.

Comment: If the result is a list of string, I suggest you could try this codes:`(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()).Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x });`